# The size of a Page Table entry

Tags: operating-system, cpu-architecture, paging, virtual-memory, page-tables

Is the size of a Page Table Entry is dependent on the total size of the logical / virtual memory space of a process?

Comment: Also, please pay attention to the tags you use: you used the [tag:tbl] tag but from its description, it's meant for questions about the troff system and is not related to page tables.  So please check the tag descriptions before adding tags.  If you can't find an appropriate tag, people will usually add them for you (I added some and deleted [tag:tbl]), but do try to avoid using tags that aren't relevant.  By the way, welcome to the site!

Comment: ok I'll do it next time ... maybe can you lead me to one of the answers please?@ Nate Eldredge

Comment: I fixed it now...

Comment: @NateEldredge: I'd guess [tbl] was a typo for [tlb], which does exist and is about how CPUs cache page-table entries. (But isn't relevant to either of the original two questions.)  But yes, checking tag descriptions would have caught that; good idea to check more than just the tag name, especially for short names.

Answer (score 5):

No, the size and format of a page table entry is generally fixed by the hardware and is always the same.  For example on x86-32 a page table entry is always 4 bytes, with the following layout (image by Alboin via  [OSDev Wiki](https://wiki.osdev.org/Paging)):

[image]

Of course, a process occupying more virtual memory will use *a larger number of* page table entries, since it will have more page tables that are marked present.  But the size of each one will still be 4 bytes.